# Iterating through a JSON file to see if the number"2017" exists in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to put a JSON file into an array, but only if the value of the key `issue_date` includes the number `2017`. This is from this API: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/ati4-9cgt.json which has parking tickets.

I only want the dates with 2017 inside of the array, that way I can later split it up into months.

How would I do this?

Thanks! Also, I am a first year in college, so my knowledge is very limited. If you use something rather complex, would you mind explaining it so I may **understand what the code is doing/means?** Thank you!

Comment: Show your own effort and code.

Comment: def filter_data(string):
        url = urllib.request.urlopen(string)
        read = url.read().decode()
        load = json.loads(read)
        array = []
        for i in load:
                if "issue_date" 

This was from a previous JSON loading function, but I just wanted to figure out a type of include function, similar to the one in JS.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really good example for learning how to parse JSON.

You can refer to this link for some help: [json guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/json/)

First thing you'll have to do is import the json library:

```
import json
```

Then you'll have to download that json file you linked and store it in the directory that your script is stored in. Use this to load the file into your program:

```
with open('jsonFileName.json', 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.loads(file.read())
```

Read up on file handling [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)

Now to go through the json and get what you need. You want to grab only the records with the issue date in 2017. You'll need to loop through the entire `json_data` variable that holds all the json data.

```
for i in data:
```

Since this is a simple json file, finding the `issue_date` is simple. Try this to get all the issue dates alone:

```
print(i["issue_date"])
```

This will print all the issues dates in the json file. However, you only want 2017 so you'll have to do some string manipulation. In this case, you want to check the first four characters of the issue date or until there's a hyphen `-`. You can use the string.split() function here.

```
if i["issue_date"].split("-")[0] == "2017"
```

The `[0]` grabs anything before the occurrence of the first hyphen `-`. Then we check if whatever was before the `-` is equal to "2017.

Now if you want the entire record, just use `i` after that `if condition` to do whatever you need to do with them.

Comment: Although I discourage people asking questions that require spoon-feeding from scratch. I'm in more admiration of people who decide to do so! Have an upvote

Comment: First year in college studying programming is really intimidating for some. I would have appreciated if my first questions on stack overflow were answered with more helpful responses like "here's where you can get help" than "fend for yourself".

Comment: Just in case the data is not so uniform, you might want to do `i.get("issue_date", "not_found").split("-")[0] == "2017"` instead of `i["issue_date"].split("-")[0] == "2017"` to avoid a key not found error...

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON looks like an array with a bunch of dictionaries in it.
Load your JSON into an array.  Let's call that array loadedJSON

parkingTickets2017 = []

```
for x in loadedJSON:    # x will be a dictionary of some parking ticket
     if x["issue-date"].startswith('2017'):
          parkingTickets2017.append(x)
```